# Install gobject module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I want to work with the dbus-python library (I just pip installed it) and they provide some nice example about making two programs communicate. In one of their .py file there is an "import gobject" line which results in a "ImportError: No module named gobject" when I run this example. I would like to know what I should install to get this module (I am working with Python3 on an Ubuntu).

When I use python2.7 this import is working and the gobject.`__file__` variable contains:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/__init__.pyc
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Install `python3-gi` and import it this way

```
from gi.repository import GObject
```

---

or so you don't have to rename all the references

```
from gi.repository import GObject as gobject
```

Comment: This no longer works, use `pip3 install PyGObject`

Answer (score 3):

Pip does not have it anymore. Check out the '[Getting Started](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)' section here and install it based on your OS.

For accessibility, based on this question's tags, here's the ["Ubuntu" section](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#ubuntu-logo-ubuntu-debian-logo-debian):

> ### Installing the system provided PyGObject:
>
> 1. Open a terminal
> 2. Execute `sudo apt install python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0`
> 3. Change the directory to where your hello.py script can be found (e.g. `cd Desktop`)
> 4. Run `python3 hello.py`
>
> ### Installing from PyPI with pip:
>
> 1. Open a terminal and enter your virtual environment
> 2. Execute `sudo apt install libgirepository1.0-dev gcc libcairo2-dev pkg-config python3-dev gir1.2-gtk-3.0` to install the build dependencies and GTK
> 3. Execute `pip3 install pycairo` to build and install Pycairo
> 4. Execute `pip3 install PyGObject` to build and install PyGObject
> 5. Change the working directory to where your `hello.py` script can be found
> 6. Run `python3 hello.py`

Answer (score -4):

I resolve problem on Centos 7 , when install pygobject2.x86_64

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31319788)